# deploy flask app in docker with odbc driver installed

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, odbc

I am trying to deploy a flask app using tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.7 and installing the odbc driver. It builds correctly but it just finishes, it is not raising any service. This app was deployed previously without the odbc driver and worked fine.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
#Base Docker image with uWSGI and Nginx for Flask applications in Python running in a single container
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.7

#By default, the application runs on port 80, you can choose a different port by uncommenting the LISTEN PORT and EXPOSE
ENV LISTEN_PORT 5000

EXPOSE 5000
# URL under which static (not modified by Python) files will be requested
# They will be served by Nginx directly, without being handled by uWSGI
ENV STATIC_URL /static
# Absolute path in where the static files wil be
ENV STATIC_PATH /app/static
# If STATIC_INDEX is 1, serve / with /static/index.html directly (or the static URL configured in this case it will be 0)
# ENV STATIC_INDEX 1
ENV STATIC_INDEX 0

# Add app
COPY ./classes /app/classes/
COPY ./models /app/models/
COPY ./config /app/config/
COPY ./microservices /app/microservices/
COPY ./templates /app/templates/
COPY ./main.py /app/main.py
COPY ./inputs /app/inputs/

# Add API files
COPY ./uwsgi.ini /app/uwsgi.ini
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /app

ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1

ENV FLASK_ENV development
ENV INPUT_PATH=/app/inputs

# Install requirements
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Install ODBC Driver
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg unixodbc-dev

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list ~/
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unixodbc
RUN mv ~/mssql-release.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile 
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Make /app/* available to be imported by Python globally to better support several use cases like Alembic migrations.
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

# Move the base entrypoint to reuse it
RUN mv /entrypoint.sh /uwsgi-nginx-entrypoint.sh

# Copy the entrypoint that will generate Nginx additional configs
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Run the start script provided by the parent image tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx which in turn will start Nginx and uWSGI
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

and here is the entrypoint.sh file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
set -e
/uwsgi-nginx-entrypoint.sh
# Get the URL for static files from the environment variable
USE_STATIC_URL=${STATIC_URL:-'/static'}
# Get the absolute path of the static files from the environment variable
USE_STATIC_PATH=${STATIC_PATH:-'/app/static'}
# Get the listen port for Nginx, default to 80
USE_LISTEN_PORT=${LISTEN_PORT:-80}
if [ -f /app/nginx.conf ]; then
cp /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
else
content_server='server {\n'
content_server=$content_server"    listen ${USE_LISTEN_PORT};\n"
content_server=$content_server'    location / {\n'
content_server=$content_server'        try_files $uri @app;\n'
content_server=$content_server'    }\n'
content_server=$content_server'    location @app {\n'
content_server=$content_server'        include uwsgi_params;\n'
content_server=$content_server'        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;\n'
content_server=$content_server'    }\n'
content_server=$content_server"    location $USE_STATIC_URL {\n"
content_server=$content_server"        alias $USE_STATIC_PATH;\n"
content_server=$content_server'    }\n'
# If STATIC_INDEX is 1, serve / with /static/index.html directly (or the static URL configured)
if [ "$STATIC_INDEX" = 1 ] ; then
content_server=$content_server'    location = / {\n'
content_server=$content_server"        index $USE_STATIC_URL/index.html;\n"
content_server=$content_server'    }\n'
fi
content_server=$content_server'}\n'
# Save generated server /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
printf "$content_server" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
fi
# For Alpine:
# Explicitly add installed Python packages and uWSGI Python packages to PYTHONPATH
# Otherwise uWSGI can't import Flask
if [ -n "$ALPINEPYTHON" ] ; then
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/$ALPINEPYTHON/site-packages:/usr/lib/$ALPINEPYTHON/site-packages
fi
exec "$@"
```